How to implement multiple embedded Python interpreters (Python 3.13 NOGIL)?
Having successfully embedded in the past multiple parallel Lua interpreters in C/C++ code (with threads running muliple cores), I thought doing the same using Python 3.13 configured with --disable-gil. However, in trying to do so, if I include the following code
    PyStatus status;
    PyConfig config;
    PyConfig_InitPythonConfig(&config);
    /* optional but recommended */
    status = PyConfig_SetBytesString(&config, &config.program_name, "PingPong");
   
    PyConfig_Clear(&config);

    PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime\n"
    "print('Today is', ctime(time()))\n");

... in each worker, when trying to run I obtain the runtime error msg:
Fatal Python error: _PyImport_Init: global import state already initialized

Is this now possible with NOGIL Python (3.13), and if so, how? Thanks.
